# How can I change my RUBY EXECUTABLE path?

Tags: ruby

When I run `gem env`, I get this:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 247) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/th/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/th/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-13
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/th/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448
     - /Users/th/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

The Ruby executable and the executable directory are different. When I install a gem and use `require 'gem_name'`, I receive an error that I cannot find the file. How can I change the executable directory to something that is consistent, such as:

```
/Users/th/.rvm/ruby
```

Also, how can I look at the .rvm directory to find the Ruby executable? I tried to show hidden files, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `which ruby` will give the path to the Ruby executable

Comment: i don't know what you mean @ArmanH

Comment: Run `which ruby` in the terminal, and it will show you the full path to the Ruby executable. By the way, there's nothing wrong with how your Ruby is installed. You may have a misconfiguration between your system's Ruby and the one installed using RVM, which may explain why you can't load gems.

Comment: more precisely, run `ls -l \`which ruby\`` or some similar command, to see its real path if appropriate.

Comment: There's no reason to do beyond `\`which ruby\``. If the system can't find it that way it's not in the path and `ls` isn't going to find it. If it's in the PATH the `ls` wouldn't return anything more useful for finding the file than `which ruby` would.

Comment: which ruby returns /usr/bin/ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using RVM but your setup has the system Ruby as the executable.

at the command line type:

```
rvm list
```

You should see a list of installed Ruby versions

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p429 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ x86_64 ]
* ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

You can use the rvm command to set the default ruby interpreter. I would install the latest version of 1.9.3 and of 2.1.0 if you don't have them. You can install new Rubies with RVM:

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p484
```

You can then set one as your default

```
rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p353 --default
```

will set 2.0.0 p353 as the default ruby interpreter unless you set it otherwise for any particular directory you are working in. That way if you want to use 1.9.3 for a certain project you can set that project to use that version.

Comment: I fixed the last one, I had `dvm` instead of `rvm`. If you use the `--default` flag, that makes it the default ruby for any directory. If you want to make a project use a different ruby, then `rvm use ruby-1.9.3...` in that application's root directory and that application will use that version of ruby.

Comment: The point of RVM is to let you specify a default ruby (and even a default gem set) and then change that for specific directories. If it is not saving the `--default` you set, then make sure your RVM is installed correctly. It usually has some entries in your `.bash_profile` or `bashrc` or in the config file for what ever shell you use.

Comment: Is the only way to change this to install a new version of ruby? Is there no way to simply change the variable to point to somewhere else?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. That's all RVM does, point towards a ruby install. If you just want to change an environment variable you could use `setenv` to make the variable point to somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Likewise if you are using rbenv, you can use the rbenv versions command:

```
$ rbenv versions
  system
* 1.8.7-p375 (set by /home/ianh/Projects/Github/railsapp_factory/.ruby-version)
  1.9.3-p484
  2.0.0-p353
  2.1.0
  jruby-1.7.9
  rbx-2.2.5
```

Use `rbenv global|local|shell version` to set the version for global, your local directory or this shell session respectively.

I type the first part, eg 1.9 and use tab completion to complete the full version string. Otherwise install the rbenv-use plugin and use `rbenv use 1.9` to swap rubies.

Type `rbenv` by itself for basic help or `rbenv help command` for help on a specific command:

```
$ rbenv 
rbenv 0.4.0-89-g14bc162
Usage: rbenv <command> [<args>]

Some useful rbenv commands are:
   commands    List all available rbenv commands
   local       Set or show the local application-specific Ruby version
   global      Set or show the global Ruby version
   shell       Set or show the shell-specific Ruby version
   install     Install a Ruby version using ruby-build
   uninstall   Uninstall a specific Ruby version
   rehash      Rehash rbenv shims (run this after installing executables)
   version     Show the current Ruby version and its origin
   versions    List all Ruby versions available to rbenv
   which       Display the full path to an executable
   whence      List all Ruby versions that contain the given executable

See 'rbenv help <command>' for information on a specific command.
For full documentation, see: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#readme

$ rbenv help use
Usage: rbenv use NAME [--global|--shell|--local]

Switches Ruby versions without having to keep patchlevels in mind.

$
```

I personally prefer rbenv as it uses a less complicated approach - see http://jonathan-jackson.net/rvm-and-rbenv for a lighthearted comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to change your RUBY EXECUTABLE path.

> **tldr;** *uninstall/reinstall the ruby version using rbenv*

In my case I was seeing a strange gem environment with two different username paths for the executable and the installation paths. This prevented correct installation since I only had write rights to one username path.

### My environment

MacOS 10.15.2
Homebrew with rbenv installed containing system and 2.6.5 versions
Multiple users having access to the rbenv

### This worked for me

Solution was to do a rbenv uninstall 2.6.5 followed by an rbenv install 2.6.5.

Other things I tried that did not fully resolve my situation included:

- Enabling the GEM_HOME and GEM_PATHS environment variables in my
  profile file.
- Uninstalling and reinstalling rbenv.